Typesetting phantom contents in nicematrix

I want to typeset a matrix, but only with a phantom contents. The output above is as desired but I want the phantom content to be inserted without having to type \RowStyle{\color{white}} for every row
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{c |[color=gray]c}[first-row,first-col,c,margin]
        \RowStyle{\color{white}}
        & 1
        & 2
        \\
        \RowStyle{\color{white}}
        3
        & A
        & B
        \\
        \Hline[color=gray]
        \RowStyle{\color{white}}
        4
        & C
        & D
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}


Why {alignat*}{4}?

The command \RowStyle can take an option nb-rows=<number>, which will perpetuate the style through the given number of rows. So you can use \RowStyle[nb-rows=3, color=white]{} to color the next 3 rows white. Unfortunately, the style does not seem to change the first-col, so you can add \NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-col = \color{white}} to achieve the effect.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-col = \color{white}}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{c |[color=gray]c}[first-row,first-col,c,margin]
        \RowStyle[nb-rows=3, color=white]{}
         & 1 & 2\\
        3 & A & B\\ \Hline[color=gray]
        4 & C & D
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}


You don't need nicematrix, nor \color{white}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{gray}\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\begin{array}{@{}w{c}{3em}|w{c}{3em}@{}}
  \rule{0pt}{5ex} & \\
  \hline
  \rule{0pt}{5ex} & \\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}


Alternatively you can do it with array and \phantom; with auxiliary local commands, input is easier and you can customize it at will.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{gray}\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\newcommand{\0}{\phantom{0}}
\newcommand{\?}{\0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0}
\begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
  \? \\ \? \\
  \hline
  \? \\ \? \\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}


